# Steam crashes on launch

Tags: 16.04, steam

After starting steam, it keeps on crashing. Here's the log:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
/bin/bash: /home/fcwe1113/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5: no version information available (required by /bin/bash)
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
grep: symbol lookup error: grep: undefined symbol: pcre_jit_stack_alloc
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
[1008/113047:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
[1008/113047:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(217)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_suid_sandbox_development.md for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160920182018)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474395618)
[1008/113047:ERROR:main_delegate.cc(779)] Could not load cef_extensions.pak
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(20160920182018)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steamwebhelper)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Created shared memory when not owner SteamController_Shared_mem
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1474415843)
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 72: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 80: saw unknown, expected number
assert_20161008112946_1.dmp[13844]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20161008112946_1.dmp
/home/fcwe1113/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 713: 13775 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
Refresh rate: 1
assert_20161008112946_1.dmp[13844]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20161008112946_1.dmp[13844]: response: CrashID=bp-8d4dc616-da8b-401b-8396-42ec52161007
assert_20161008112946_1.dmp[13844]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20161008112946_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-8d4dc616-da8b-401b-8396-42ec52161007''
```